# Add Administrators to a Facebook app if only Developer role is filled

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-developers

Taken from off-topic question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748388/how-to-add-administrators-to-an-app-if-only-developer-role-is-filled by anon user (only visible by Stack Overflow users with reputation >10k, first closed as off-topic, later deleted)

> I am the designated developer for 11 apps however no administrator exists. Some apps need to be deleted and other users added to other roles.

Is there a way to add an admin?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting oneself (the only administrator) from one of the test applications results in

> Must specify at least one developer who has administrator permission.

So it's possible that the original administrator deleted their Facebook account or it got suspended. Or your app was victim of this bug: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18848

You should contact Facebook directly.

<sub>Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748796/321505 (only visible by Stack Overflow users with reputation >10k)</sub>

Comment: Both links are now dead :/

Comment: @Henrik added notes about the Stack Overflow links.